# clear TextField when focused using javascript

Tags: javascript, testing, user-interface, automation

i want to delete the text from textfield which i set earlier.
note: not using javascript for web development or CSS etc., i am newbie in automation testing and designing test script for GUI testing.

Comment: `document.getElementById("textfield_element_id").value = "";`

Comment: As said in response, you can use `onfocus="this.value = '';"` which will do the work great. But maybe you are looking for a specific use such as the `placeholder` attribute ? (html5)

Answer (score 0):

How about `onfocus="this.value = '';"` in your input tag?

Note:
There are far better ways of doing this via more scripting and the use of libraries like jQuery, but this is the most basic version.

Answer (score 0):

@ Shellster/Ian

Dhruv is asking without using JS/CSS.

from automated scripts like selenium you have to write some code like

```
Driver.getElementById("id").sendKeys("");
```

Regards,
Amit